# Python 2D array reformating to named dict

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a 2D array in this format:

```
arr = [
[100000, 5],
[100060, 3],
[100120, 7],
...
]
```

I want it to reformat it as dict:

```
dct = {
x_values: [100000, 100060, 100120],
y_values: [5, 3, 7]
}
```

What is the best performance way to do it?

**Note: values are not always integer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably faster:

```
In [19]: %timeit d = dict(zip(('x', 'y'), zip(*arr)))
553 ns ± 18.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [18]: d
Out[18]: {'x': (100000, 100060, 100120), 'y': (5, 3, 7)}
```

Edit: marginally at least

```
In [38]: %%timeit
    ...: dict_ = {"x_value":[], "y_value":[]}
    ...: for x_value, y_value in arr:
    ...:             dict_["x_value"].append(x_value)
    ...:             dict_["y_value"].append(y_value)
    ...:
620 ns ± 20 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a faster solution:

```
arr = [[100000, 5],
       [100060, 3],
       [100120, 7],
      ]

dict_ = {"x_value":[], "y_value":[]}
for x_value, y_value in arr:
    dict_["x_value"].append(x_value)
    dict_["y_value"].append(y_value)
print(dict_)
```